# Second instance of angular controller does not display declared variables

Tags: angularjs, ajax, laravel

I have a page that has two instances of the same controller, the first one is loaded with the page and the second comes from an ajax request. Inside the controller I have a variable called filter, with initial value equal to "status". When I try to display this variable in the first instance it displays correctly. But when I show this variable in the second instance it looks undefined, it shows Filter: @ {{mClerk.filter}}. The changeFilter function works in both instances.

My controller

```
app.controller('clerkCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $compile, $timeout, notifyService, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) {

    this.filter = 'status';

    this.changeFilter = function (filter) {
        this.filter = filter;
    };

});
```

First Instance,

```
<div ng-controller="clerkCtrl as Clerk">
Filter: @{{Clerk.filter}} <!-- OK -->
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h2><i class="zmdi zmdi-accounts-list zmdi-hc-fw"></i> Lista</h2>
                </div>

                <div style="padding: 0px 20px;">
                    <div class="card-body table-responsive">
                        <table datatable="" dt-options="Clerk.dtOptions" dt-columns="Clerk.dtColumns"
                               class="table table-striped"></table>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
```

Second instance, from a ajax request:

```
<div ng-controller="clerkCtrl as mClerk">

Filtro: @{{mClerk.filter}} <!-- FAILED -->

<button ng-click="mClerk.changeFilter('date')">Change filter</button>
</div>
```

Function that brings the page to the second instance,

```
$scope.loadPage = function (page) {
        $http.post(page, [], $scope.config)
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.modal.body  = $sce.trustAsHtml(response.data.body);
                $scope.modal.title = $sce.trustAsHtml(response.data.title);

                $('#modalx').modal('show');
                $scope.reloadPlugins();

                setTimeout(function () {
                    $compile(angular.element('.modal-body').contents())($scope);
                }, 0);

            });

    };
```

Comment: It could be that  `$('#modalx').modal('show)` and `setTimeout` are not triggering a `$digest` so when the second instance of the controller is loaded, the controller won't update the view until you manually run a `$digest` via after triggering the `ng-click` directive, but I'm kinda sceptic since you're running a `$compile`. Try using the `$timeout` service if it makes any difference, that's the only advice I could give you.

Comment: The [AngularJS $timeout service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) wraps a raw `setTimeout` and properly integrates the function with the AngularJS digest cycle.

Comment: Mixing jQuery with AngularJS is problematic. I would recommend using a library such as [Angular UI bootstrap.modal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal) which has done all the AngularJS framework integration and testing.